# Choosing an OS for Jmeter load generator server

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am currently reviewing a Jmeter framework set up. I wanted check get some feedback if there are any specific advantages of choosing a Linux server to run Jmeter as Load Generator over using a Windows server.

Are there any specific advantages in terms of the cost, efficiency if I choose Linux over Windows to run Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project website](https://jmeter.apache.org/)

> The Apache JMeter™ application is open source software, **a 100% pure Java application** designed to load test functional behavior and measure performance

it means that JMeter will run whenever Java runs and Java will run whenever it's possible to install [Java Virtual Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine). So for Java/JMeter there is no difference between Linux and Windows

I can think of the following "advantages":

- Linux can have "minimal" installation with only base system, an [SSH server](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/server) and JVM while in Windows in majority of cases you will have GUI causing increased resources consumption
- Pricing. As of now Home version of Windows costs $139 and Pro version is $199, for extremely high loads you may even have to go for [Windows Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server) options,theoretically you can use [trial versions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise) for assessment but if you plan to have load generators up and running longer than the allowed trial period - you will have to pay. The majority of Linux distributions are free as long as you don't need "support" from the distribution vendors

When it comes to "efficiency" I cannot state anything as it mainly depends on hardware, specific Windows or Linux distribution and mainly the nature of your test as both Windows and Linux might need to be properly tuned. You need to make sure that JMeter isn't the bottleneck as if JMeter isn't capable of sending the requests fast enough you will get false negative results so be extremely careful while calculating [how many users you can run on this or that load generator](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what%E2%80%99s-the-max-number-of-users-you-can-test-on-jmeter).